# How to map two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have Five columns.

**E.g.**

1. Column1: Name
2. Column2: surname
3. Column3: mapping
4. Column4: Mapped data

Columns contain data like

```
      Name         Surname        Mapping    Name1   Surname1
  1   ABC          1  AAAA          3         ABC      QQQQ
  2   XYZ          2  XXXX          1         XYZ      AAAA
  3   OPQ          3  QQQQ          4         OPQ      QQQQ
  4   RST          4  RRRR          2         RST      RRRR
```

Now my aim is to map name column to surname by using mapping column and result should be stored at Name1 and Surname1 column. I have more data in Name and Surname column, by writing number in Mapping column it will automatically map the surname to Name (the choice is given to user for entering number in mapped column then map the data accordingly) and result should be copied in Name1 and Surname1.

I am not getting any idea to achieve this using VBA. coding Plz help me.....

Comment: Is the mapped data correct? I was expecting the surnames to be mapped in the order QQQQ, AAAA, RRRR, XXXX. If I've got this wrong, please let us know how you're calculating the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Vlookups to map? 
Vlookup(Lookup_Value,Table_array,col_index_number,[range_lookup])
Vlookup(firstname, the last name column you are referencing, the column number of the first name column, false)
-false is for exact matches 
-I've also pasted a helpful link below. Goodluck!

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into the mapped data row and it should do what you want

```
Formula MappedData()
Dim CurrentCell As Range
CurrentCell = Application.Caller.Address

MappedData = Cells(CurrentCell.Row,1).Value & " " & Cells(Cells(CurrentCell.Row,3),2).Value

End Formula
```

Comment: is it work if i have long data in Name column and Surname Column

Comment: Yes it will.  Because the data is attached to a string, it will automatically convert the data type to a string

Comment: If i change data in column 3 (mapping data to different numbers)....then is it work for that new data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Vlookup, just a concatenate:

[image]

If you want to have the numbers in front of your surname, use the second option.

The formulas for copy&paste:

`=CONCATENATE(B2;" ";OFFSET($C$1;D2;0))`

`=CONCATENATE(B8;" ";RIGHT(OFFSET($C$7;D8;0);LEN(C8)-FIND(" ";C8;1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't realize you wanted to have them together in the same column like what you have above. The concatenate function works:
http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excelformulas/using-concatenate-to-combine-names/1/

or if you go to excel you can go to the `data` tab, and click on `text to columns.`

1. Click on the data tab
2. Click on Text to columns
3. Check `Delimited`
4. Choose the delimiter that separates your data
5. Modify your column data format (if it's general, number, etc.) in this case it would be general.
6. Click finish

and you're done!