# How to map two column using another column data

Tags: vba, excel

I have Five columns.

**E.g.**

1. Column1: Name
2. Column2: surname
3. Column3: mapping
4. Column4: Mapped data

Columns contain data like

```
      Name         Surname        Mapping    Name1   Surname1
  1   ABC          1  AAAA          3         ABC      QQQQ
  2   XYZ          2  XXXX          1         XYZ      AAAA
  3   OPQ          3  QQQQ          4         OPQ     RRRR
  4   RST          4  RRRR          2         RST      XXXX
```

Now my aim is to map name column to surname by using mapping column and result should be stored at Name1 and Surname1 column. I have more data in Name and Surname column, by writing number in Mapping column it will automatically map the surname to Name (the choice is given to user for entering number in mapped column then map the data accordingly) and result should be copied in Name1 and Surname1.

I am not getting any idea to achieve this using VBA. coding Plz help me.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882299/how-to-map-two-columns)

Comment: Do Name/Surname columns have two values - or are you just showing them together? Do they actually have two separate columns for # and text?

Comment: It could be that I'm missing something, but I don't see any consistent mapping taking place in the data you've presented.

Comment: Sry i made mistake in problem statement ......i will edit it thanks for ans .....

Comment: Name and surname are two different colums .....there are five columns colum1 Name colm2 Surname colm3 Mapping colm4  Name1 colm 5 Surname1

Answer (score 0):

Amar, there are certainly plenty of ways to go about this using Excel's built in functions, however, since you asked about a VBA solution, here you go:

```
Function Map(n)
    Map = Cells(n + 1, 2)
End Function
```

Placing the above code into the VBA editor of your project will allow you to use this custom function in the same way you would any of Excel's builtin functions. That is, entering `=Map(C3)` into any cell should give you the result you're after (where C3 is the cell containing your mapping number). The function works by returning the data in [row n (defined in your mapping column) +1 (to account for the header row); column 2 (the column containing your surname)]. The data in column "Name1" will always be the same as that in column "Name" (so it seems). So the function in your "Name1" column would simply be `=A2`

If this does not solve your problem, or you need further guidance, please let me know.

**Supplement**

@Amar, the comment by @freakfeuer is spot on. VBA is really overkill for something as simple as this and, as he points out, portability and security are both significant drawbacks. Offset is a fine alternative.

Comment: @Amar - There are some drawbacks you can avoid if you don't have to use VBA. Portability and security are two of them. So I would recommend to use 'OFFSET' unless you really need a VBA solution.